# View tab missing between Review and Developer tabs in Excel 2011 on macOS Sierra

Tags: microsoft-excel, macos

Screen shot of preferences of MS Excel which shows that view tab is not there. The view tab between Review tab and Developer TAB is missing. See screen shot below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no View Tab in the Excel 2011 Ribbon. What feature did you need to use?

Comment: This is actually correct. There is no View tab option in 2011. Maybe this was a Windows Excel feature?